# Reordering nodes in increasing order in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
data1 = { 'node1': [2,2,3,6],
     'node2': [6,7,7,28],
     'weight': [1,2,1,1], }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['node1','node2','weight'])
```

I want to rename the node1 and node 2 in the data1 according in increasing order.
Nodes are 2 3 6 7 28 so they become 1 2 3 4 5 respectively.

So the dataframe becomes-

```
data1 = { 'node1': [1,1,2,3],
     'node2': [3,4,4,5],
     'weight': [1,2,1,1], }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['node1','node2','weight'])
```

The data looked like this before

[image]

but now looks like this

[image]

Comment: How should the resulting dataframe look like?

Comment: @Dark yes edited

Comment: you can accept the answer if it was helpful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Factorizing by sorting and assigning by reshaping i.e

```
df1[['node1','node2']] = (pd.factorize(np.sort(df1[['node1','node2']].values.reshape(-1)))[0]+1).reshape(-1,len(df1)).T

    node1  node2  weight
0      1      3       1
1      1      4       2
2      2      4       1
3      3      5       1
```

Another approach with melt and factorize and renaming with dict

```
vals = pd.factorize(df1[['node1','node2']].melt().sort_values('value')['value'])

to_rename = dict(zip(vals[1],np.unique(vals[0]+1)))
# {2: 1, 3: 2, 6: 3, 7: 4, 28: 5}

df1[['node1','node2']] = df1[['node1','node2']].apply(lambda x : x.map(to_rename))
# Also df1[['node1','node2']] = df1[['node1','node2']].replace(to_rename) Thanks @jezrael

  node1  node2  weight
0      1      3       1
1      1      4       2
2      2      4       1
3      3      5       1
```

Comment: the format of the dataframe has changed from before

Comment: Why is there a unnamed column we are not even touchining the dataframe in that way you end up in an unnamed column

Comment: I have attached the image of how the dataframe looked like before which was the same as the reproducible example in the question.

Comment: the second approach

Comment: Whats the result with the first line of the code? Reshaping approach

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160440/discussion-between-chaitali-sarkar-and-dark).

Answer (score 5):

Use [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html) with reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and then [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df2 = (df1.set_index('weight', append=True)
          .stack()
          .rank(method='dense')
          .astype(int)
          .unstack()
          .reset_index(level=1))
print (df2)
   weight  node1  node2
0       1      1      3
1       2      1      4
2       1      2      4
3       1      3      5
```

Comment: After saving it to csv file the format changes.I have attached the images in the question.

Comment: You need `df.to_csv(filename, index=False)` for not save first column to csv

Answer (score 1):

Or we can using replace :-)

```
ary=np.concatenate(df1.iloc[:,:2].values)
mapdf=pd.DataFrame({'data':pd.Series(ary).astype('category').cat.codes.add(1),'maper':ary}).set_index('maper')
df1[['node1','node2']]=df1[['node1','node2']].replace(mapdf.data.to_dict())

df1
Out[1631]: 
   node1  node2  weight
0      1      3       1
1      1      4       2
2      2      4       1
3      3      5       1
```

Comment: I have used replace. Now its cat.codes you like this one I guess

Comment: @Dark a ha:-) , you got it then.:-)